# PHP $_POST information not coming up

Tags: php, html, http

My PHP will not work. I'm trying to use `$_POST` to collect information from the form and nothing is coming up.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<form action="test2.php" method="post">                                         
    First Name:<br />
    <input type="text" name="firstname" /><br />
    Last Name:<br />
    <input type="text" name="lastname" /><br /><br /><br />
    Address:<br />
    <input type="text" name="address" /><br />
    City:<br />
    <input type="text" name="City" /><br />
    Province:<br />
    <input type="text" name="province" /><br /><br /><br />
    Phone:<br />
    <input type="text" name="phone" /><br />
    Email<br />
    <input type="text" name="email" /><br /><br /><br />
    Select Desired Apartment: <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="onebed" />One Bedroom<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="twobed" />Two Bedroom<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="threebed" />Three Bedroom<br /><br /><br />
    Rental Type:<br />
    <input type="radio" name="renttype" value="weekly" />Weekly<br />
    <input type="radio" name="renttype" value="monthly" />Monthly<br /><br /><br />
    Start Date:<br /><input type="date" name="startingdate" /><br /><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Here is test2.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body>
    Registration_Number: <br /> 
    Name: <?php echo $_POST['firstname']; ?> <br />
    Address: <?php echo $_POST['address']; ?> <br /> 
    Email: <?php echo $_POST['email']; ?> <br />
    Appartment_Type: <br />
    Rental_Type: <br />
    Starting_Date: <?php echo $_POST['startingdate']; ?> <br />
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Define not working! What is the error you get?

Comment: Use this for error reporting: `<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
 ?>` And it works fine for me!

Comment: Are you sure you have PHP installed and configured properly?

Comment: After I fill out the form and submit it, it loads the php page and where the $_POST should be shown it is blank.

Comment: can you give us the output of echo `'<pre>'. print_r($_POST, true) .'</pre>';`

Comment: The output of the echo is nothing. it does not display anything.

Comment: If you can't see the output of `$_POST`, try `var_dump($_SERVER);`. That should output something. Otherwise, there might be something wrong with your server or PHP install. Your HTML/PHP seems to check out fine.

Comment: Besides not having anything set for your `name="renttype"` and `name="type"`, worked beautifully.

Comment: are you running a webserver? Like apache or nginx or IIS? Is PHP working with in the context of that server?

Comment: Yes I am running on a webserver and I'm thinking that might be it. But I don't know what would be wrong

Comment: @Kevin See my answer... does `<?php echo "it's working";` work?

Comment: @Fred-ii- How would I use $_POST for form inputs using checkboxes or radio buttons?

Comment: Same as you did for the others. `$radio = $_POST['renttype'];` and `$check = $_POST['type'];`

Comment: @Tivie It does not work

Comment: What type of webserver, Xampp, Wamp, Mamp, other?

Comment: Then your webserver is not configured properly... that's a completely different question

Comment: I"m using my schools webserver.

Comment: Maybe your school's admin isn't letting you do stuff like that on their server. Contact the sysadmin then, it may be a permissions issue.

Answer (score 1):

First assure php is working properly

create a test php file with this

```
<?php
 echo "it's working";
```

and navigate to it using the browser

it should show the message `it's working`

---

Second step is assuring everything is working with your form.

change your test2.php to this:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
var_dump($_POST);
```

you should see the values of the form posted

Answer (score 0):

try adding `value` attributes to all your input tags. Sometimes browsers will not send these fields. You would see a blank page if you do not have PHP configured to display errors.

```
<form action="test2.php" method="post">                                         
    First Name:<br />
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="" /><br />
    Last Name:<br />
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="" /><br /><br /><br />
    Address:<br />
    <input type="text" name="address" value="" /><br />
    City:<br />
    <input type="text" name="City" value="" /><br />
    Province:<br />
    <input type="text" name="province" value="" /><br /><br /><br />
    Phone:<br />
    <input type="text" name="phone" value="" /><br />
    Email<br />
    <input type="text" name="email" value="" /><br /><br /><br />
    Select Desired Apartment: <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="onebed" />One Bedroom<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="twobed" />Two Bedroom<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="threebed" />Three Bedroom<br /><br /><br />
    Rental Type:<br />
    <input type="radio" name="renttype" value="weekly" />Weekly<br />
    <input type="radio" name="renttype" value="monthly" />Monthly<br /><br /><br />
    Start Date:<br /><input type="date" name="startingdate" value="" /><br /><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```